# How do I find if a PEP has already been written and rejected?

Tags: python, pep

As an example, in Python I often mind myself writing:

```
if failed:
    raise SomethingFailed(failed)
```

or even

```
if ready:
    return result
```

Wouldn't it be nice if I could write?

```
while True
   raise SomethingFailed(failed) if failed
   return result if ready
   <keep on trying>
```

Perl actually has such semantics.

It seems so obvious and is not in the language that somebody must have written a pep proposing it which has been rejected. A few Google searches don't produce any usable results.

Well I would write a PEP if it's never been proposed. But that can't be the case?

So how do you verify your idea is novel, and not already rejected 17 times?

Comment: For the raise case SomethingException could have a raiseif method which becomes ugly: SomethingFailed.raiseif(failed, failed)

Comment: Is your question actually about how PEPs work or how to do what you have shown as an example?

Comment: My question is generic. If I have a brilliant idea, how do I check it has not already been proposed and rejected in the Python pep system?

Comment: But I'm intrigued by your suggestion:  how to do what you have shown as an example. I know how to do a (return or raise) but I specifically mean return ... if <cond> which does nothing if the condition is false

Comment: Well according to your clarification that would be a *different* question.

Comment: "Wouldn't it be nice if I could write?" No, it makes it harder to read. You have to read the whole line, just to find out in the end, that it isn't executed at all. Having the condition in the beginning is a lot clearer.

Comment: Did you mean to ask about **pip**?

Comment: I'm interested in both pip, and pep. pip to share it, and pep to promote it

Answer (score 1):

There is an index of PEPs published here:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/

You need to read them and see if what you want to propose has been written before.

The index also categorizes them into "accepted", "rejected", etc.

Comment: I had already searched that page for raise|return. There are 4 rejected return proposals, and 0 rejected raise. But there must be 10s of thousands of rejected peps. That's just a digest or maybe only rejected recently

Comment: I don't think that there are more peps than are listed here.

Comment: @Francis Why do you think there ought to be thousands?  Out of the box, Python has well defined semantics and functionality

Comment: @OneCricketeer Because I find it hard to believe I'm the first to come up with such an awesome enhancement. <sarcasm> Hmmm maybe I should not bother and just write my own language.

Comment: @FrancisCagney why not just propose it then?

Answer (score 0):

> Wouldn't it be nice if I could write

First, a while loop doesn't replace your `if failed` statements... Otherwise, you **can** write something close to that ... Doesn't need a PEP

```
class SomethingFailed(Exception):
    pass 

def func(): 
    result = None
    failed = False  # example 
    while True:
        if failed: raise SomethingFailed(failed) 
        else:
             try:
                 result = do_work()
             except:
                 failed = True
        # keep on trying
    return result 

print(func())
```

Comment: I could indeed do if and raise as a one liner. But I thought such one liners were an anti pattern, and unpythonic?

Comment: Doesn't mean it won't run

Comment: I cannot deny that. Now what I actually want to do is write a pep proposing emap, and efilter and/or put my implementation into PyPy. I think it's pypy. When I do python3 -m pip install awesome. I'm about to answer my own question with more details on emap, efilter.

Comment: I assume "e" means exception/error? `map` should already be able to capture (returned) Error subclasses and `filter` should be able to remove them. If you use `raise` rather than `return`, though, then it would stop the `map` iteration

Comment: No actually e means enhanced. raise and return if are red herrings. I though the pep list was incomplete. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The reason I asked about raise if, and return if was because I was pondering how to release my first shareware.

I've written 2 functions emap, efilter which extend map, and filter.

So I know I have to package them up and upload them. If I think they should replace the existing map and filter I should write a pep proposing this.

```
efilter(isinstance, MyClass, mylist)
filter(lambda x: insinstance(x, MyClass), mylist)


efilter(op, a, b, mylist, hello=True)
filter(lambda x: op(x, a, b, hello=True), mylist)
```

emap follows the same semantics as efilter but the first arguments can also be a list or string

```
emap([0], mylist)
map(lambda x: x[0], mylist)

emap([0, 1, 2], mylist)
map(lambda x: x[0][1][2], mylist)
```

The last argument in the list is one of False, True, None, ... are short macros for ´__name__´, ´__qualname__´, ´__module__´, type()

```
emap([0, False], mylist)
map(lambda x: x[0].__name__, mylist)
```

The source code of efilter is pretty trivial

```
def efilter(op, *args, invert=False, **kwargs):
    return filter(lambda x: invert != op(x, *args[:-1], **kwargs), args[-1])
```

emap is rather more complicated.

Note emap, and efilter behave exactly like map and filter if given their accepted arguments

So I guess I'll package it as pip installable and upload it.
I've been reading about pips, and understood it was normal to write a pep describing your package and proposing it become a standard library, or even be incorporated into the language.

Obviously have uploaded a package I want people to know about it. And love it. Writing an article on medium seems a pretty obvious step.

Comment: You might want to look at this, or just contribute to it https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: I did look through the link. They have a lot of functions, but nothing that I think replicates my emap, efilter. I'm about eliminating or hiding the underlying lambda. But I notice they have their own domain. I quite like that idea. So I can put it on my website, have git repositories, and then upload it?

Comment: If you want to create your own library, sure. Or you can submit your code to theirs as a PR